# Ionic and sails.js architecture

Tags: architecture, ionic-framework, sails.js

I'm new to both sails and ionic. I am trying to figure out the best way to setup this project on my Mac. Since I will want to deploy my app to the app store I know that one cannot contain the other. I have a test ionic app (myApp) located under user, does the sails.js framework sit right next the myApp folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sails app can reside wherever you like. You might want a const in your app that contains the location to your server though.  This would change depending on your environment (prod/dev)